# Purpose of QcoreApplication in basic Qt console program

Tags: c++, qt

Why does QCoreApplication a(argc, argv) exist inside main(int argc, char *argv[]) in a Qt console application? What does it do? What is its purpose?
if I remove it, a program like the following runs without issues

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "animal.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    { // this is just a dummy scope for the destructor to work

        // create instances of class animal
        animal cat(NULL, "Garfield");
        animal dog(NULL, "Azor");

        // perform actions with the object's functions
        cat.weight = 10;
        qDebug() << "Cat Weight in Lbs:" << cat.weightInLbs();
        cat.speak("meow");

        // perform actions with the object's functions
        dog.weight = 35;
        qDebug() << "Dog Weight in Lbs:" << dog.weightInLbs();
        dog.speak("wooof");
     }

    //return a.exec();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It provides event loop so asynchronous API could be used (it does more but this one is most important). Your code doesn't do anything meaningful what uses asynchronous API.

Comment: There is also some initialization done. The documentation explains this:  [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.15/qcoreapplication.html#details](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.15/qcoreapplication.html#details) ***It also handles the application's initialization and finalization, as well as system-wide and application-wide settings.***

Comment: If you do not need for your cats-and-dogs app, you can remove it.

Comment: Marek R and drescherjm, the program is just a dummy implementation of a class. I just couldn't understand why that  QCoreApplication  object is by default in main().